# Why the cpu performance counter kept reporting 0% cpu usage?

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, performancecounter

```
PerformanceCounter cpuload = new PerformanceCounter();
cpuload.CategoryName = "Processor";
cpuload.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
cpuload.InstanceName = "_Total";
Console.WriteLine(cpuload.NextValue() + "%");
```

The output is always 0%, while the `cpuload.RawValue` is like 736861484375 or so, what happened at `NextValue()`?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The first iteration of the counter will always be 0, because it has nothing to compare to the last value.  Try this:

```
var cpuload = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
Console.WriteLine(cpuload.NextValue() + "%");
Console.WriteLine(cpuload.NextValue() + "%");
Console.WriteLine(cpuload.NextValue() + "%");
Console.WriteLine(cpuload.NextValue() + "%");
Console.WriteLine(cpuload.NextValue() + "%");
```

Then you should see some data coming out. It's made to be seen in a constant graph or updated scenario...that's why you don't come across this problem often.

Here's the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx):

> The method nextValue() always returns
> a 0 value on the first call. So you
> have to call this method a second
> time.

Answer (score 26):

First retrieve first value (would be 0)

```
NextValue();
```

Then wait for 1000 milisec

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Then retrieve second value which is the true cpu usage.

```
NextValue();
```

The code should look like this:

```
float perfCounterValue = perfCounter.NextValue();

//Thread has to sleep for at least 1 sec for accurate value.
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

perfCounterValue = perfCounter.NextValue();

Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", perfCounterValue);
```