# C# WPF Threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I've been following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) guide to the WPF threading model to create a little application that will monitor and display current and peak CPU usage. However, when I update my current and peak CPU in the event handler, the numbers in my window don't change at all. When debugging, I can see that the text fields do change but don't update in the window.

I've heard it's bad practice to go about building an application like this and should go for a MVVM approach instead. In fact, a few have been surprised that I've been able to run this without a runtime exception. Regardless, I'd like to figure out the code example/guide from the first link.

Let me know what your thoughts are!

And here is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="UsagePeak2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CPU Peak" Height="75" Width="260">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <Button Content="Start"  
        Click="StartOrStop"
        Name="startStopButton"
        Margin="5,0,5,0"
        />
    <TextBlock Margin="10,5,0,0">Peak:</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="CPUPeak" Margin="4,5,0,0">0</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Margin="10,5,0,0">Current:</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="CurrentCPUPeak" Margin="4,5,0,0">0</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is my Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public delegate void NextCPUPeakDelegate();

    double thisCPUPeak = 0;

    private bool continueCalculating = false;

    PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;

    public MainWindow() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartOrStop(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (continueCalculating)
        {
            continueCalculating = false;
            startStopButton.Content = "Resume";
        }
        else
        {
            continueCalculating = true;
            startStopButton.Content = "Stop";
            startStopButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Normal, new NextCPUPeakDelegate(GetNextPeak));
            //GetNextPeak();
        }
    }

    private void GetNextPeak()
    {

        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

        double currentValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();

        CurrentCPUPeak.Text = Convert.ToDouble(currentValue).ToString();

        if (currentValue > thisCPUPeak)
        {
            thisCPUPeak = currentValue;
            CPUPeak.Text = thisCPUPeak.ToString();
        }

        if (continueCalculating)
        {
            startStopButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle,
                new NextCPUPeakDelegate(this.GetNextPeak));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your UI still responsive once you click 'Start'? (does the button change to 'Stop', and can you click it?).  Trying to read the code, it looks like you would keep invoking `GetNextPeak()` over and over on the UI thread, not on a background thread, so I would think the entire UI would be locked up.  I could be wrong though. I haven't tried copy/pasting the code into a WPF project.

Comment: Not entirely sure of what advice you're looking for, but your delegate is looping over a thousand times a second.  It's going as fast as the CPU can handle which means it's gobbling up CPU cycles like an FPS game might -- or worse. Also I should mention the perf counter doesn't read higher than 0.0 for me (inaccurate).

Comment: @rally25rs Yeah, my UI is perfectly responsive... the button text does change. 

@Erode Doesn't seem to lock up or anything, besides when I loop again I set the priority to `SystemIdle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few problems here.  First, you are doing work on the main thread, but you're doing it in a *very* roundabout way.  It's this line right here that allows your code to be responsive:

```
startStopButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle,
    new NextCPUPeakDelegate(this.GetNextPeak));
```

From the [`BeginInvoke` method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Executes the specified delegate **asynchronously** at the specified priority on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with.

Even though you're sending this at a high rate, you're queuing work on the UI thread by having the post back into the message loop occur on a background thread.  This is what allows your UI to be at all responsive.

That said, you want to restructure your `GetNextPeak` method like this:

```
private Task GetNextPeakAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    // Start in a new task.
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        // Store the counter outside of the loop.
        var cpuCounter = 
            new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

        // Cycle while there is no cancellation.
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Wait before getting the next value.
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            // Get the next value.
            double currentValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();

            if (currentValue > thisCPUPeak)
            {
                thisCPUPeak = currentValue;
            }

            // The action to perform.
            Action<double, double> a = (cv, p) => {
                CurrentCPUPeak.Text = cv.ToString();
                CPUPeak.Text = p.ToString();
            };

            startStopButton.Dispatcher.Invoke(a, 
                new object[] { currentValue, thisCPUPeak });
        }
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

Notes about the above:

- The call to the [`NextValue` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue.aspx) on the [`PerformanceCounter` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t90y2y1) must have some time expire before values start coming through, as per [Dylan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11870851/50776).
- A [CancellationToken structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) is used to indicate if the operation should be stopped.  This drives the loop that will continuously run in the background.
- Your method now returns a [`Task` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) which represents the background information.
- Synchronization around the `thisCPUPeak` value is *not* needed, as the singular background thread is the *only* place where it is read and written to; the call to the [`Invoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) on the [`Dispatcher` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) has copies of the `currentValue` and `thisCPUPeak`  values passed into it.  If you want to access the `thisCPUPeak` value in *any* other thread (UI thread included) then you need to synchronize access to the value (most likely through the [`lock` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Now, you'll have to hold onto the `Task` on the class level as well and have a reference to a [`CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx) (which produces the `CancellationToken`):

```
private Task monitorTask = null;
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = null;
```

And then change your `StartOrStop` method to call the task

```
private void StartOrStop(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If there is a task, then stop it.
    if (task != null)
    {
        // Dispose of the source when done.
        using (cancellationTokenSource)
        {
            // Cancel.
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        // Set values to null.
        task = null;
        cancellationTokenSource = null;

        // Update UI.
        startStopButton.Content = "Resume";
    }
    else
    {
        // Update UI.
        startStopButton.Content = "Stop";

        // Create the cancellation token source, and
        // pass the token in when starting the task.
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        task = GetNextPeakAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

Note that instead of the flag, it checks to see if the `Task` is already running; if there is no `Task` then it starts up the loop, otherwise, it cancels the existing loop using the `CancellationTokenSource`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not seeing the UI update because you aren't using the performance counter correctly. The first time you query the processor time performance counter, it will always be 0. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2181828/684831).

```
cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

double currentValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();

Thread.Sleep(1000);

currentValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();
```

Something as simple as this will fix the problem, but you probably want to develop a more robust solution, taking into consideration some of the remarks in the comments above.

Comment: That got it "working", though now it will only read CPU usage values of 0 or 100. I added `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);` in `GetNextPeak()` to slow it down a little bit.

Comment: @Tory As suggested in the question I linked, some time must pass between queries to the performance counter to get accurate values. Add the Sleep in between the queries and it should fix your problem.