# how do i get current read/write rate for each Storage device in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net

i'm trying to get the disk read/write rate for each storage on the OS. for example i have 2 storage devices, one is 250GB SSD and the other is 500GB HDD, i want to check what's the current read/write rate for each of them.

i haven't had any luck to find a method to get close achieving this, i'd appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [performance Counter for disk read / write time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524370/performance-counter-for-disk-read-write-time)

Comment: On Windows, you can use the built-in Resource Monitor to monitor disk activity, including read and write rates.

Press Ctrl + Shift + Esc to open Task Manager, then go to the "Performance" tab and click on "Open Resource Monitor" at the bottom. In the Resource Monitor, navigate to the "Disk" tab to see disk activity details.

Comment: You can use the Performance Monitor tool (perfmon) to create custom performance counters to monitor disk read/write rates.

Press Win + R to open the Run dialog, then type perfmon and press Enter.
In Performance Monitor, click "Performance Monitor" in the left panel.
Click the green plus icon to add a counter.
Select the desired disk under "LogicalDisk", then select the "Disk Read Bytes/sec" and "Disk Write Bytes/sec" counters.
Click "Add" and then "OK" to start monitoring.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods i tried to use this method, but i get this error
```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index '' was read from the registry. Performance counters on the machine may need to be repaired.'
```
i tried to solve that problem but i went down a rabbit hole and it seemed to be unreliable

Comment: @ZoraizHammad i don't want to just monitor it for myself, i want to programatically get that data