# Retrieve Cpu usage asynchronously in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cpu-usage, performancecounter

I want to retrieve the cpu usage of my system using c#. I have read that I must call the method `NextValue()` then wait for about a second and call the `NextValue()` method again.
I want to do that asynchronous to not delay my UI thread so I have written following code

```
    public Task<float> GetCpuPerformanceAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            CpuPerformance.NextValue();
            Task.Delay(1000);
            return CpuPerformance.NextValue();
        });
    }
```

This is the declaration of `CpuPerformance`

```
CpuPerformance = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
```

At the first time calling the asynchronous method as shown above it returns me the actual cpu usage but then calling it again after few secons it only shows 0 or 100 which doesn't coincide with the usage shown in my task manager

Can somebody help me solving this please?

Comment: Does it actually delay? I'd expect to have to `await Task.Delay(1000)` ...

Comment: Note that you're not awaiting your call to `Task.Delay`, so it won't actually wait at all. You probably want `public async Task<float> GetCpuPerformanceAsync() { CpuPerformance.NextValue(); await Task.Delay(1000); return CpuPerformance.NextValue(); }`. That said, I'm not sure that calling `NextValue()`, throwing the result away, waiting, then calling it again will bring you any benefit

Comment: _"I have read that I must ..."_ - can you give a reference where you read that?

Comment: Thanks @canton7 your suggestions seems to work :-) Learned something new!

Comment: @Fildor Read that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181828/why-the-cpu-performance-counter-kept-reporting-0-cpu-usage

Comment: Ah, now it's clear. And what I was thinking. You don't have to do that _always_. If you create a new Performance Counter, it needs to "warm up". I.e. it first needs a value to compare to, so the output value is actually a valid value. So, if you keep that instance, just warm it up, then you can simply call `NextValue` without delay.

Comment: @Fildor So in fact I need to delay the first time retrieving a value after the initialization of ```PerformanceCounter``` and then I just can call ```NextValue()``` without delaying?

Comment: @Fildor Cause I didn't understand what you mean with warm it up? Could you show me please what you mean?

Comment: I'll write up a short answer with what I think should work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, dotnetfiddle won't allow me PerformanceCounters, but this should work anyway:

```
public class Helper // Of course, you do not necessarily need an extra class ...
{
    // Lazy Pattern: Will create an instance on first usage.
    private static Lazy<PerformanceCounter> CpuPerformance = new Lazy<PerformanceCounter>(() => {
        // this will be used as factory to create the instance ...
        // 1. create counter
        PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        // "warm up"
        pc.NextValue();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // return ready-to-use instance
        return pc;
        // ^^ this will be executed only _once_.
    });

    // Read-Only Property uses Lazy to ensure instance exists, then use it.
    public static float CpuTimeInPercent {
        get { return CpuPerformance.Value.NextValue(); }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine("Performance: {0}%", Helper.CpuTimeInPercent);
```

Comment: @MarcelMüller note that this will pause your thread for a second the first time it accesses `CpuTimeInPercent`, which you were presumably trying to avoid in your question

Comment: I guess you can tweak this to not block the UI Thread on creation. This was just inteded to show what the Source meant by what I referred to as "warm up". @canton7

Answer (score 5):

This is an alternative to @Fildor's answer using the technique they came up with, but which avoids sleeping the thread the first time that `CpuTimeInPercent` is accessed.

```
public static class Helper
{
    private static readonly Task<PerformanceCounter> performanceCounter = GetCounter();

    private static async Task<PerformanceCounter> GetCounter()
    {
        PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        // "warm up"
        pc.NextValue();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        // return ready-to-use instance
        return pc;
    }

    public static async Task<float> GetCpuTimeInPercentAsync()
    {
        var counter = await performanceCounter;
        return counter.NextValue();
    }
}
```

This will start executing `GetCounter()` at some point before `performanceCounter` is executed for the first time (it might be when the assembly is loaded, it might be when `GetCounter()` is called, the runtime has a lot of freedom here). If you call `GetCpuTimeInPercentAsync` while it's doing the warm-up, then it will wait until it's finished and then get the CPU usage. If you call it subsequently, or after it's finished the warm-up, then it will return the CPU usage straight away.

Comment: Excellent! I'll leave mine anyway, if just to show the usage of `Lazy` ...

Comment: @Fildor Please do -- I think it's right that OP accepts your answer, as you did the legwork. I just wanted to show how it could be done with tasks, and it's a bit too long for a comment.